# Error Loading EJB3 into JBoss 5.1

Tags: dependencies, seam, jboss5.x, ear

I have been wrestling with this problem for two days and still have not been able to figure it out. I am trying to deploy a J2EE project that uses Seam, JSF 2, and is a EJB3 project. This is the error that I am getting:

```
10:51:56,720 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/tag
10:51:57,517 INFO  [config] Initializing Mojarra (1.2_13-b01-FCS) for context '/tag'
10:52:00,204 INFO  [ServletContextListener] Welcome to Seam 2.0.2-FP
10:52:03,673 WARN  [Component] Component class should be serializable: addressExtendedDataModel
10:52:03,689 WARN  [Component] Component class should be serializable: cbf
10:52:03,689 WARN  [Component] Component class should be serializable: exportBean
10:52:03,689 WARN  [Component] Component class should be serializable: importBean
10:52:03,860 WARN  [Component] Component class should be serializable: volumeBean
10:52:03,860 WARN  [Component] Component class should be serializable: wavePickerBean
10:52:03,970 WARN  [HDScanner] Failed to process changes
org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-    ejb.jar,name=AddressDaoImpl,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressDaoImpl,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear/TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar#TagEJB' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressDaoImpl,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
   Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressDaoImpl,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressServiceImpl,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
   Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressServiceImpl,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:TagTestAndCleanUp-ear/VolumeDaoImpl/local-com.pnc.conversion.tag.dao.VolumeDao' **")
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressServiceImpl,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:TagTestAndCleanUp-ear/AddressDaoImpl/local-com.pnc.conversion.tag.dao.AddressDao' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressServiceImpl,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressServiceImpl,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressServiceWrapper,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressServiceWrapper,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:TagTestAndCleanUp-ear/AddressServiceImpl/local-com.pnc.conversion.tag.services.AddressService' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressServiceWrapper,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressServiceWrapper,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=MenuServiceImpl,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=MenuServiceImpl,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:TagTestAndCleanUp-ear/WaveTestingPhaseDaoImpl/local-com.pnc.conversion.tag.dao.WaveTestingPhaseDao' **")
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=MenuServiceImpl,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:TagTestAndCleanUp-ear/TagDaoImpl/local-com.pnc.conversion.tag.dao.TagDao' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=MenuServiceImpl,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=MenuServiceImpl,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=MenuServiceWrapper,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=MenuServiceWrapper,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:TagTestAndCleanUp-ear/MenuServiceImpl/local-com.pnc.conversion.tag.services.MenuService' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=MenuServiceWrapper,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=MenuServiceWrapper,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=TagDaoImpl,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=TagDaoImpl,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear/TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar#TagEJB' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=TagDaoImpl,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
   Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=TagDaoImpl,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=VolumeDaoImpl,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=VolumeDaoImpl,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear/TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar#TagEJB' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=VolumeDaoImpl,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=VolumeDaoImpl,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=WaveTestingPhaseDaoImpl,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=WaveTestingPhaseDaoImpl,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear/TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar#TagEJB' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=WaveTestingPhaseDaoImpl,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=WaveTestingPhaseDaoImpl,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "persistence.unit:unitName=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear/TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar#TagEJB" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=TagDatasource,service=DataSourceBinding" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:name=TagDatasource,service=DataSourceBinding' **")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=MenuServiceImpl,service=EJB3>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:TagTestAndCleanUp-ear/WaveTestingPhaseDaoImpl/local-com.pnc.conversion.tag.dao.WaveTestingPhaseDao' **, ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:TagTestAndCleanUp-ear/TagDaoImpl/local-com.pnc.conversion.tag.dao.TagDao' **
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=MenuServiceWrapper,service=EJB3>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:TagTestAndCleanUp-ear/MenuServiceImpl/local-com.pnc.conversion.tag.services.MenuService' **
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressServiceImpl,service=EJB3>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:TagTestAndCleanUp-ear/AddressDaoImpl/local-com.pnc.conversion.tag.dao.AddressDao' **, ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:TagTestAndCleanUp-ear/VolumeDaoImpl/local-com.pnc.conversion.tag.dao.VolumeDao' **
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=TagDaoImpl,service=EJB3>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear/TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar#TagEJB' **
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=VolumeDaoImpl,service=EJB3>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear/TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar#TagEJB' **
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=TagDatasource,service=DataSourceBinding" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:name=TagDatasource,service=DataSourceBinding' **
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressServiceWrapper,service=EJB3>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:TagTestAndCleanUp-ear/AddressServiceImpl/local-com.pnc.conversion.tag.services.AddressService' **
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=AddressDaoImpl,service=EJB3>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear/TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar#TagEJB' **
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear,jar=TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar,name=WaveTestingPhaseDaoImpl,service=EJB3>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear/TagTestAndCleanUp-ejb.jar#TagEJB' **

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1008)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:954)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:870)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.checkComplete(MainDeployerAdapter.java:128)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:416)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What could be causing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a deploy problem. Try to post the full stack trace, probably the problem is before that message. This is a messages that says "your ejbs are not deployed yet".

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while and I was using eclipse . Eclipse's auto publish option was set to 1 sec interval . So sometimes jboss was trying to unzip before the ear file is fully copied . 
Go to Window-> Show View -> Servers and expand the Publishing tab 
Now set the publishing interval to 6s(in my case)